# Gradle Error: "Plugin with id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin' not found" - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I'm encountering a Gradle error in my Flutter project that I can't seem to resolve. When I try to build and run my Flutter app, I get the following error:

```
Could not apply requested plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0'] as 
it does not provide a plugin with id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'. This is caused by an 
incorrect plugin implementation. Please contact the plugin author(s).
> Plugin with id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin' not found.
```

This error is triggered in the build.gradle file of my app module on this line:

```
apply plugin: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'
```

Please let me know if you need any further information to assist me in troubleshooting this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of that Should not you have something like this? 
`apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"`

Comment: @cyberail not anymore :) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/123511

Comment: I still use that in my app and no errors. 
What is your flutter version ?

Comment: any new on that ?

Comment: I solved it by upgrading flutter to 3.16.0

Comment: @raviKiran did you find the solution of this problem? i m also facing error on this line
Error resolving plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0']

Answer (score -1):

try to upgrade flutter:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: I have clear install Android Studio, Flutter, Dart. This is not help me.